# How to make a child node clickable in ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i'm using this sample codes   samples\android-8\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view\ExpandableList1 . I want to click child node but i cant follow my codes. Do you have any simple solution to handle it?

My codes are below.

```
public class Option_Hakkimizda_Bir extends ExpandableListActivity {

ExpandableListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up our adapter
    mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Sample menu");
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, R.string.expandable_list_sample_action);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();

    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
        Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Child " + childPos + " clicked in group " + groupPos,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        Toast.makeText(this, title + ": Group " + groupPos + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * A simple adapter which maintains an ArrayList of photo resource Ids. 
 * Each photo is displayed as an image. This adapter supports clearing the
 * list of photos and adding a new photo.
 *
 */
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    // Sample data set.  children[i] contains the children (String[]) for groups[i].
    private String[] groups = { "   Su Yalıtım", "  Isı Yalıtımı", "    Çatı Kaplama Malzemeleri", "    BTM Optigreen Yeşil Catilar","  BTM Schüco Solar Güneş Enerjili Çatı Sistemleri" };
    private String[][] children = {
            { "BTM Su Yalıtım Örtüleri", "BTM PVC Su Yalıtım Örtüsü Polypan", "BTM Surma Esaslı Su Yalıtım Örtüleri" },
            { "BTM Polpan Isı Yalıtım Levhası", "BTMPlus Dış Cephe Isı Yalıtım Sistemi- MANTOLAMA Sistemi" },
            { "BTM Çatı Kaplama Malzemesi Shingle", "Oluklu Bitümlü Çatı Kaplama Malzemesi","BTM Kiremit Altı Su Yalıtım Membranı","BTM Taşlı Çatı Kaplama Örtüsü Poliroof" },
            { "Ekonomik Çatı Çözümü", "Eğimli Çati Çözümü" },
            { "Ince Film Çözümler", "Poli-Mono Kristal Moduller" }
    };

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    public TextView getGenericView() {
        // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 64);

        TextView textView = new TextView(Option_Hakkimizda_Bir.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        //textView.setTextSize((float) 11.5);
        // Center the text vertically
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
        // Set the text starting position
        textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
        return textView;
    }

    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
        textView.setTextSize((float) 13.0);
        //convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        return textView;

    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = getGenericView();
        textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
        textView.setTextSize((float) 15.0);
        return textView;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the onItemClick in the child view?